# why is this code not changing the screen white?

Tags: python, pygame

i have followed a tutorial to make this code but for some reason it is not working and turning the screen white. i am doing it in vscode on python 3.11.4 and i have definitely downloaded pygame.

i used this code:

```
import pygame

from pygame.locals import (
    K_UP,
    K_DOWN,
    K_LEFT,
    K_RIGHT,
    K_ESCAPE,
    KEYDOWN,
    QUIT,
)

pygame.init()
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
```

it is turning the screen black not white.

Comment: Are you missing this `pygame.init()`?

Answer (score -1):

The `while running` loop has no `pygame.display.update`. This means that whatever you "draw" on the screen isn't actually being shown, because the display isn't being updated.

You need to add the `pygame.display.update()` function at the end of every iteration. Like this:

```
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    pygame.display.update()
```